# How to prevent access to path in Aws CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website with CloudFront on top. Example uvwxyz.com. How can I prevent access to any request path that looks like so /no-please?
uvwxyz.com/mypage/no-please or uvwxyz.com/no-please.
How can I achieve this by using CloudFront by setting a template with CloudFormation.

Comment: if you want to serve 403 etc when someone accesses uvwxyz.com/mypage/no-please , there are two ways, one way is to use WAF on cloudfront and block if URI contains the path or you can write a lambda@edge function to serve custom html page with 4xx response if uri matches the path, waf would be cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the access using Signed URLs or signed cookies.

[Serving Private Content with Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

> Many companies that distribute content over the internet want to
>   restrict access to documents, business data, media streams, or content
>   that is intended for selected users, for example, users who have paid
>   a fee. To securely serve this private content by using CloudFront, you
>   can do the following:

- > Require that your users access your private content by using special
  >   CloudFront signed URLs or signed cookies.
- > Require that your users access your content by using CloudFront URLs,
  >   not URLs that access content directly on the origin server (for
  >   example, Amazon S3 or a private HTTP server). Requiring CloudFront
  >   URLs isn't necessary, but we recommend it to prevent users from
  >   bypassing the restrictions that you specify in signed URLs or signed
  >   cookies.